# Is there better way to 'touch' a row than performing a dummy update?

Tags: postgresql

I use the [`xmin` system column](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/ddl-system-columns.html) to implement a form of [optimistic locking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimistic_concurrency_control), and sometimes need to 'touch' the row to bump `xmin` without actually updating the row. I currently just do a 'dummy' update:

```
create table t(id integer);
insert into t(id) values(1);
insert into t(id) values(2);

select xmin::text from t where id=1
/*    
|  XMIN |
---------
| 87159 |
*/

update t set id=id where id=1

select xmin::text from t where id=1
/*
|  XMIN |
---------
| 87196 |
*/
```

<sub>*[(SQL Fiddle)](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/6cfa6/2)*</sub>

I'm curious whether there is another way of bumping the `xid` without doing an update, analogous to the unix `touch` command?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, if you want to change the xmin, then it needs to be ensured that other transactions can still see the old version of the row, so you need to make a copy with the new xmin, which you do with an `UPDATE`.  You can reduce the impact of this by updating a non-indexed column, to get the benefit of HOT.

Of course, this whole line of thinking is dubious, and perhaps you should be using some other facility altogether.

Comment: What would you do instead, use a 'version' column and a sequence?

Comment: That certainly sounds more sane.